# Pause event listeners in the background

Tags: javascript, css, prompt

I have a event listener

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
};
```

but I am opening a modal window (just a simple `div` with `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0`).

The problem is that while I am typing in a form in this modal, the key event listener is still listening in the background, so when the modal window is again hidden, a lot of changes has been done to the page because of the key event listener.

How do I pause the event listeners in the background while the modal window is open? I want the modal window to behave like a `prompt()` which makes everything else on the page wait for it to be done.

Comment: You can't pause event listeners. What you can do, is to set a flag variable when a modal is opened, and in listeners check, if the flag is set. Then reset the flag when closing the modal. You can also detach events when opening a modal, and attach again when closing it. A third option would be to set a keyup listener to the modal, and prevent propagation of the event.

Comment: Great suggestions! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily detach the event handler by:

```
document._onkeyupHolder = document.onkeyup;
document.onkeyup = null;
```

And when you are done with the modal window, attach it back:

```
document.onkeyup = document._onkeyupHolder; 
document._onkeyupHolder = null;
```

Of course, to fully simulate a prompt, you will have to do the same for other events as well.

Comment: Is this what, for instance, bootstrap do in their modals?

Comment: @Jamgreen Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think bootstrap modals will block the event handlers on the main html.